# How to get an actual file from tmp?

Tags: php, laravel

I am uploading a file using curl via an API. The problem is, am getting a temporary file other than the real file. I have tried $request->file->getClientOriginalName() it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like the below code:

```
<input type="file" name="category_img">

$productImage = $request->file('category_img');
$imageName = $productImage->getClientOriginalName();
```